# How to make categories, subcategories, subsubcategories with mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have three classes

> ```
> public class CountryListViewModel
> {
>     public IEnumerable<CountryViewModel>
>     Countries { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class CountryViewModel
> {
>     public string CountryName { get; set; }
>     public string State { get; set; }
>     public IEnumerable<CityViewModel> Cities { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class CityViewModel
> {
>     public string CityName { get; set; }
>     public string CityLink { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Using linq to entity grouping by country and it works as designed.
but I also have to group by state. Could you please help me to change my query to group first by country and than by state?

```
var query = from c in _db.MyTable
                        where c.IsActive && c.Country == country 
                        group c by c.Country
                            into loc
                            select new CountryViewModel()
                            {
                                CountryName = loc.Key,
                                Cities = loc.Select(s => new CityViewModel() { CityName = s.City, CityLink = s.City }).Distinct()
                            };
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by myself

```
var query = from c in _db.MyTable
            where c.IsActive && c.Country == country 
            group c by new{ c.Country, c.State}
            into loc
                    select new CountryViewModel()
                                {
                                    CountryName = loc.Key.Country,
    State = loc.Key.State,
                                    Cities = loc.Select(s => new CityViewModel() { CityName = s.City, CityLink = s.City }).Distinct()
                                };
```

Comment: cool, congrats, so if you would ask, i want to group by state and country, i would say the same, but you were talking about categories, subcategories and subsubcategories. So your solution does not fit your requierments, i just answered you were asking for in the title, a hierarchical solution. But I´m happy you found what you where looking for!

Comment: "using linq to entity grouping by country and it works as designed. but I also have to group by state." next time just read question

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from i in query 
        group i by i.state into st 
        select new with { .State = st.Key,
                          .Countries = (from c in st group c by c.Country into ctr 
                                        select new with {.Country = ctr.Key,
                                        .Cities = ctr})
```

No Idea if this works, just typed it in here without testing or looking at your datamodel.

Comment: and what is not working, you must be more specific I cannot see what your debugger says?

Comment: object not set to an instance of an object

Comment: either you put in your code, how you´ve written it, then debug it with some breakpoints and come back with some useful info, or we(I) cannot help you. Where should I see from what object is not set to an instance?

Comment: you wrote code which you didn't test. it's not a solution for my question. with out putting in solution it doesn't look correct

Comment: we are not here to give you a fully functioning solution, we are here free offering our time to help. If you want a solution go to a professional and pay him, then you dont have to come here and post somethink like, yaah, "error". hmm anything else "yaaa, em, object not set to an instance", hmm.. what object? "yaaah, it´s your fault, your solution doesnt work, you even didnt test hit".

Comment: ok... one more time. Please provide your code using my (not working) solution, that you adjusted to your needs, so we can find your problem. You could help me find your problem, if you run your application in debug mode, so we can find, what object is nothing.

Comment: Do me a favor if you cannot offer a solution which works don't waste your time and mine. you are trying to get more score but I need a working solution. Maybe someone else help me. thank you

Comment: you know what, in my solution there i cannot find any null references as it is. I wrote a solution from scratch not because i want to score, but because i want to help. But you seem not to try working with me on your problem, you want somebody solve your problem. Why you just dont tell me where the problem is, why you dont pass in the code you now have adjusted with my solution. I wrote this solution many times, so maybe there is one charachter wrong or some tiny thing, but the whole concept works perfectly in my solutions.

Comment: see my answer. that I was looking for - very simple and straight forward